# google-github-actions/auth failed with did not inject $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN or $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

In github actions I'm running an action that is trying to use github to GCP federated id:

```
     # see https://github.com/marketplace/actions/authenticate-to-google-cloud#setup
  - id: 'auth'
    name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
    uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
    with:
      workload_identity_provider: 'projects/1234/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-github-pool/providers/my-github-oidc-provider'
      service_account: 'my-github-sa@projxyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

I'm getting:

```
Run google-github-actions/auth@v0

Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: retry function failed after 1 attempt: 
gitHub Actions did not inject $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN or 
$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL into this job. 
This most likely means the GitHub Actions workflow permissions are incorrect, or this job is being run from a fork. 
For more information, please see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic- 
token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token
```

I'm looking at the referenced doc but I'm not seeing anything useful.

How to I get GH to inject those values?

Comment: Your answer is correct in specific cases but you are leaving out many details on the type of account you are using, the identity roles, etc. Those details are required to understand why configuring the GITHUB_TOKEN was required for your use case. In most cases, your solution is not required. Additional details for future readers: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I needed to add:

```
jobs:
   my_job:
   # Need to add these 3 lines to add "id-token" with the intended permissions.
   permissions:
     contents: 'read'
     id-token: 'write'
```

This is documented here: https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#usage

Answer (score 2):

For me, what I missing are

1. Ensure the value for workload_identity_provider is the full Provider name, not the Pool name:

```
- projects/NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/POOL
+ projects/NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/POOL/providers/PROVIDER
```

2. Need to have permission

```
permissions:
     contents: 'read'
     id-token: 'write'
```

Check out this
https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth/blob/main/docs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md